# Glassfish admin console display no login page

Tags: glassfish

I'm running glassfish 3.1.2 on Debian 6 (a VM on Mac OS X 10.8 host). Default domain1 starts OK, system listens on tcp port 4848, the 'Admin console loading' page is displayed for a duration of at least one coffee-break. When I reload a page as advised (as I'm not redirected anywhere), the page displays the copyright message, and nothing else happens neither with reload nor without. This was tried with Firefox (Java functionality tested at java.net page), Chrome and Safari.

Please advise.

PS The log file has this to say:
        [#|2013-01-22T15:41:17.998+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=22;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ApplicationDispatcher[] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create XMLStreamReader or XMLEventReader from a javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.jaxpSourcetoXMLInputSource(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:283)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:143)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:115)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:110)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.plugin.ConsolePluginService.init(ConsolePluginService.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.plugin.ConsolePluginService.getIntegrationPoints(ConsolePluginService.java:428)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.PluginHandlers.getIntegrationPoints(PluginHandlers.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.handlers.ThemeHandlers.getThemeFromIntegrationPoints(ThemeHandlers.java:102)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.beforeCreate(LayoutComponent.java:348)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutComponent.getChild(LayoutComponent.java:288)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.buildUIComponentTree(LayoutViewHandler.java:556)
        at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.LayoutViewHandler.createView(LayoutViewHandler.java:255)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:247)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:809)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:671)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:476)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:355)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.admingui.common.security.AdminConsoleAuthModule.validateRequest(AdminConsoleAuthModule.java:232)
        at com.sun.enterprise.security.jmac.config.GFServerConfigProvider$GFServerAuthContext.validateRequest(GFServerConfigProvider.java:1171)
        at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.validate(RealmAdapter.java:1452)
        at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:551)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:623)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
    |#]

Answer (score 1):

Replacing open-jdk with Oracle newest version has fixed the matter.